# What are the advantages of MVVM pattern to the user?

Tags: user-interface, mvvm, user-interaction

I'm seaching a lot about MVVM pattern.

The advantages that I found are about the developer/design, architecture, etc.

But what are the advantages to the user? (User interaction)

Comment: None.  Users use the user interface.  Users use not the code.

Comment: Direct advantages: none. Indirect: faster development, better software quality, less time to have extended functionalities, truly agile development process...

Comment: Discussions and opinion based questions are off topic. Please read the [tour] again and pay attention to what is on topic.  Knowing that will gain you rep, enough of which you can get on chat and chew over questions like this all day.